# How to validate an Internet address in an ASP.NET MVC textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do I validate an Internet address in an ASP.NET MVC textbox like www.gmail.com or http://www.hotmail.com?

I want to implement jQuery client-side validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good way to validate internet address

```
var address = $('#vcr_LinkAddress').val();
var j = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
if (!j.test(address)) {
//If address is invalid
}
else
{
//address is valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to parse it, take a look a the Uri class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) (which has build in url validation rule) with ASP.NET MVC 2 model validation. [Here](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2010/04/unobtrusive-asynchronous-form-in-aspnet.html) you can read how to create an asynchronous form in ASP.NET MVC which uses DataAnnotations and jQuery Validation Plugin (it also shows how to create validators which make use of built in client side rules of this plugin)